Sign text keep disappearing on Minecraft Java 1.20.2 server
I'm on a lightly modded "Vanilla+" Java 1.20.2 server and sign text keeps disappearing. I can still click on the sign to see the text but other than that it disappears after a couple of minutes. It seems to be only an issue on my side, no-one else on the server is experiencing this. I've checked all the video settings that seem like it would affect it, to no avail. Is this a known bug and is there any way to fix it?
The Modpack I'm using is this one on Modrinth
https://www.modrinth.com/modpack/telidos
I also have the Controlify mod installed and the BSL shader pack

What mods do you have installed? Please [edit] your question and add this information,
